# Java Reflection constructors orders

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

Does the order of class constructs return different results in reflection?

I have a problem using reflection. Here is an example:

```
public class A{
    public A()
    {
        do something here
    }
    public A(int i)
    {
        do something here
    }
}
```

Then, in another class, I use reflection to get the constructors with getConstructors() method. But here is the problem. It returns only the constructor with parameters.

So I modified the code and changed the order of constructos as:

```
public class A{
    public A(int i)
    {
        do something here
    }
    public A()
    {
        do something here
    }

}
```

Then, it returns two constructors correctly.

Another interesting point is OpenJDK works fine with two examples, but Sun JDK does not. And I have many classes like this, SunJDK works fine in some of them, and wrong in others. Very strange.

Any reason?

Edit:
It is a big project, here is some code for the reflection

```
Constructor<?>[] constructors = handlerClass.getDeclaredConstructors();
for (Constructor<?> constructor : constructors) {
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = constructor.getParameterTypes();
```

System.out.println("- " + constructor.toString());

```
    if (nonConnection == true && parameterTypes.length == 0) {
        return constructor;
    } else if (parameterTypes.length > 1) {
        continue;
    } else if (parameterTypes.length == 1) {
        Class<?> parameterType = parameterTypes[0];
        if (TableManipulator.class.isAssignableFrom(parameterType))
        {
            return constructor;
        }
    }
}
```

handlerClass is the class to get constructors from.

ps. I had a look at the bytecode, the bytecodes are the same except the order of the constructors.

edit:
I added a System.out to display the constructors after getParameterTypes(). It shows only one constructor.... with the old ordering, but two constructors with the new ordering.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to get the constructors via reflection.

Comment: Are you sure? `getConstructors` should return *all* of a class's constructors. `getDeclaredConstructors` does something different. I'd be pretty surprised if either exhibited non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: I just tested, it works as you expect with sun jdk 1.6.0_20.

Comment: witch java version are you using ? I tested it with 1.6.0_24, 1.5.0_15 and 1.4.2_16 return all the same number: 2

Comment: Is `nonConnection` always true? Can you remove it?

Comment: Your claim is improbable in the extreme. Without showing your code it is impossible to comment further.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey noConnection could be true or false

Comment: @Helic So it may or may not "see" the constructor with no arguments. Can you confirm this is not the source of the problem?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, yes, it is source of the problem.

Comment: I edited the post with System.out to print the constructors, the problem still exists. pls see the edited post

Comment: Can you give us a simple example which should reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
public class A{
    private /* or non-public */ A()
    {
        do something here
    }
    public A(int i)
    {
        do something here
    }
}
```

and you use getConstructors, only the second one shows.

If you use [getDeclaredConstructors()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors%28%29) you will get all of them. I would try this method and see if it fixes your problem.

---

EDIT: I would check you don't have

```
public class A {
    public A A() // not a constructor
    {
         // do something
    }
    public void A() // not a constructor
    {
         // do something
    }
}
```

---

Can you remove `nonConnection`? If this is false, it won't return the default constructor.

Comment: In that case, that constructor doesn't appear to be there.